# How To Make Dynamic Input With Laravel Splade + Component Vue JS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

ive implement Custom Vue components in laravel splade to make dynamic input:

do field repeater using Custom Form components (https://splade.dev/docs/custom-form-components). Here is my code

In `Peneliti.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
            <input v-model="fields[index]" class="input w-full max-w-xs" />
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click.prevent="removeField(index)">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <button @click.prevent="addField" class="btn btn-primary">Add Field</button>
        
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { ref  } from "vue"

    const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

    const fields = ref([''])

    const addField = (event) => {
        fields.value.push("")
        emit('update:modelValue', fields.value)
    }

    const removeField = (index) => {
        fields.value.splice(index, 1)
    }
    
</script>
```

In `create.blade.php`

```
        <Peneliti v-model="form.peneliti" />
```

In Controller

```
dd($request->peneliti);
```

But i want to make dynamic input more than 1 form inputs, like have a field:

- name
- age
- address

al of this make in array to submit polymorphism laravel

How to solve this?

I want to create many fields like:

- Name
- age
- address

all of this is dynamic input polymorphism